Formulate weight lifting as MILP problem
Consider two variables $x_1$, $x_2$ describing how high a weight is in two succeeding states. I need to minimize effort of lifting the weight, but I don't care about dropping the weight: $\min w\cdot\max\{0; x_2 - x_1\}$. This is not too hard to define as LP (Linear Programming) using additional variable $z$:
$\min w\cdot z$
subject to:
$z \geq x_2 - x_1$
$z \geq 0$
I use this formula in larger model where $x$ is in fact a vector and sum of it is maximized and there are some other constraints on $x$, but I think the problem can be simplified to the presented above WLOG.
Now let's modify the original problem: add an edge which prevents the weight from falling under certain height $b$. $x_1$ and $x_2$ represent position of a lever lifting the weight; it is free to move if lower than $b$. Now I believe I need to optimize
$$\min w\cdot\max\{0; \max\{x_2, b\} - \max\{x_1, b\}\}$$
I need to construct MILP (or better LP) model for this modified problem.


Mixed Integer Linear Programming

I find this problem quite general. The same formulation could be applied for accumulator with nonlinear penalty, e.g. to penalize battery overcharging.
